# Issue with EventListening in Classes

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, class, event-listener

I've got my `main.as` file which (at the moment) only contains a call to a class function `initDB()`

My `initDB()` function on my other class fires as expected. `initDB` is intended to load an XML file and the file activity is monitored by a listener, which on completion sets a global variable.

I trace the global variable after the call to `initDB()` in my `main.as` and it displays `null`, but  I think this is because the listener isn't included within the call to `initDB()`

Instead of:

```
- initDB();
- associated event listener which activates upon completion of XML parse
- trace to variable
```

I'm getting:

```
- initDB();
- trace to variable
- associated event listener which activates upon completion of XML parse
```

I've not a clue how to get around this, anybody got any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that you tagged your question oop. Your design isn't really OOP, but instead is procedural.  You should not have global variables at all.  Instead, your main controller should notify subcomponents of things they care about, usually by calling methods or setting properties on them. http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons

Comment: The OOP aspect comes from the fact that it's Class Communication as opposed to Function Communication. Prodedural usually concerns just function to function. Classes are a step into OOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main.as

```
  private var other:OtherClass;
  private var global:Object;

  private function init():void
  {
        //instantiate your other class
        other = new OtherClass();
        other.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE , completeHandler );
        other.initDb();
  }

  private function completeHandler( event:Event ):void
  {
       other.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE , completeHandler );

       //global could be a property of the event, 
       //rather than the class itself...

       trace("Event Complete" );
       global = other.global;          
  }
```

In your other class

```
  public function initDb():void
  {
       //add listener for load complete
       trace("Called initDb");
  }


  private function loadComplete():void
  {
       //remove listener for load complete
       // set your global variable here...
       //then dispatch event!

       trace("XML load complete");
       dispatchEvent( new Event( Event.COMPLETE ) );
  }
```

This is only a basic example for the flow of actions, the event may not have to be dispatched by the class itself. The same flow can be achieved in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

Listeners are asynchronous. In your case, that means the trace of the global variable does not wait for the load to complete.

Instead, what you should do is have your listener set your global variable and call any methods you want to perform after the load completes.